# Addressbook Project - java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, javafx, addressbook

i code at the moment a project for my university.
i get a java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException if i execute my project.
Have to few experience to find the bug :/.

Hope someone can help me!

Kind Regards

http://www77.zippyshare.com/v/M6fqdMaI/file.html

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to visit the [help] to learn how to use this site, and how to ask questions here.  If you really do not have enough experience to begin to debut, you should be talking to your professor, not asking here.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking what the cause of your exception is

```
try {
...
} catch(InvocationTargetException e) {
    e.getCause().printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: So your question is answered? You have the error and the line at which it occurs...